# Javascript array not populating properly

Tags: javascript, json, flot

I am using Flot to display a graph of timeseries data on a page. The chart works fine with a single dataset, however I want to add the capability of multiple data sets grouped by tags.

I have the JSON outputs formatted to what they need to be to work correctly, I am just running into a problem when combining multiple datasets prior to being plotted.

I would like to get the datasets into the seriesArray array, however with the code below that array isn't populated when I am plotting the graph.

There is data in the tagsList array at the end of the function so I set up the seriesArray to be populated in the same manner to no avail.

What am I missing?

```
var plotarea = $("#placeholder");
var data;   
var plot;
var tagsList=[];
var seriesArray = [];
$.getJSON("/items/getTags.json", function(tagsJSON) {
  $.each(tagsJSON, function(key, val) {
    tagsList.push(val.name);
    $.getJSON("/data/"+val.name+".json", function(json) {
      data = [{label:val.name, data:format(json)}];
      seriesArray.push(data);
    });  
  });
  plot = $.plot(plotarea , seriesArray, {series:{ lines: {show: true},points: {show:true}},
      xaxis: {
          mode: "time",
          timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",
          tickDecimals: 0,
          minTickSize: [2,"day"]
      },
      yaxis: {
          minTickSize: 1,
          tickDecimals: 0
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: $.getJSON is an ajax call, which is asynchronous.

Comment: Do you really need to make a separate AJAX call for every tag?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to make an AJAX call for every tag if there was a way to format the JSON data to allow me to read it in once with the tags and then parse it from there. I am using Rails with the acts_as_taggable_on gem with 

@tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(:all)

in my controller to put the tag values into JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until all your AJAX calls to `/data/tag.json` are finished. You can use  [`$.when().then()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to do that.

```
var plotarea = $("#placeholder");
var data;
var plot;
var tagsList=[];
var seriesArray = [];
$.getJSON("/items/getTags.json", function(tagsJSON) {
    var deferreds = [];
    $.each(tagsJSON, function(key, val) {
        tagsList.push(val.name);
        deferreds.push($.getJSON("/data/"+val.name+".json", function(json) {
            data = [{label:val.name, data:format(json)}];
            seriesArray.push(data);
        }));
    });
    $.when(deferreds).then(function(){
        plot = $.plot(plotarea , seriesArray, {series:{ lines: {show: true},points: {show:true}},
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",
                tickDecimals: 0,
                minTickSize: [2,"day"]
            },
            yaxis: {
                minTickSize: 1,
                tickDecimals: 0
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That makes sense, however it is giving an error that it is missing a ")" after the argument list for the deferreds.push($.getJSON call that I can't seem to resolve by adding a ")" after the function call. Thoughts?

Comment: @amarcy Fixed. Here's a tip, if you use and IDE like eclipse or Webstorm, it shows you where the problem is

Comment: Thanks, I was only using firebug. That fix allowed the page to load, however I am seeing a blank plot as if there isn't any data in the series array.

Going through firebug's console and doing an alert on seriesArray when it executes .push(data) it appears that as the JSON pages are called the number of objects contained in seriesArray decreases to zero. I would expect it to start at zero objects and increase as data is pushed into it. Thoughts?

Comment: @amarcy I find that hard to believe... Can you create a reduction in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Looks like the $.when is expecting a single parameter, not an array.

Using $.when.apply(null,deferreds) instead of just $.when(deferreds) did the trick.